# How to detect whether Notifications Panel is expanded?

Tags: android, reflection

I found this way to expanded Notifications Panel

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar");
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
Method showsb;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
} else {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
}
showsb.invoke(sbservice);
```

After looking into source, I also found collapsePanels method to collapse the notification

But I cannot find any way to detect the notification panel status

Because I want to check whether it is opened or closed, and then decide I should open it or close it

How can I know this status?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if notification shade is pulled down in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161458/how-to-tell-if-notification-shade-is-pulled-down-in-android)

Comment: Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323637/why-cant-i-find-a-reference-to-the-statusbarmanager-class-directly. Using the hidden statusbarmanager in your app might not be the greatest of ideas

Comment: Since the code is in service, so it is impossible track by activity. And this is a very important function in my app, And the reflection is the only way, so I need use any possible method to implement it

Comment: I understand. You can still use the solution in that link, but you need to have some way to inform the service that the app is active/inactive

Comment: ~"**to expanded Notifications Panel**"  Are you saying to detect notification panel status, or to expand it?

Comment: Check this for a working solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53509108/how-to-detect-when-the-notification-system-bar-is-opened/53509109#53509109

Answer (score 0):

Though it's very late but it might help someone

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59561899/9640177)

> You can use below method for detecting the notification panel pull,
>
> In your manifest file
>
> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>`
>
> In your activity override the onWindowFocusChanged() and write the
>   below code.
>
> This uses the permission
>
> ```
> @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
> try
> {
>     if(!hasFocus)
>     {
>         Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
>         Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
>         Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
>         collapse .setAccessible(true);
>         collapse .invoke(service);
>     }
> }
> catch(Exception ex)
> {
>     if(!hasFocus)
>     {
>         try {
>             Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
>             Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
>             Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
>             collapse .setAccessible(true);
>             collapse .invoke(service);
>
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>             e.printStackTrace();                
>         }
>         ex.printStackTrace();
>     }
> } }
> ```