# Is there a way to check if notification bar is pulled down?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I am developing an app to detect all the user actions performed on the screen.  So how can I check if the user pulls down the notification bar?

Will this be possible with accessibility service??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if notification shade is pulled down in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161458/how-to-tell-if-notification-shade-is-pulled-down-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no proper way to add a callback or any kinds of detection when the notification bar is pulled down.

That is because Android apps are meant to be designed in such a way that the interaction between the notification bar does not affect the functioning of the applications being used in any way.